# Periodically updating scope variable with event

Tags: angularjs

I'm listening to an event within my controller:

```
$scope.$on('time:update', function(event, args) {
  console.log('Update -> ' + args.time);
  $scope.time = args.time;
});
```

My view is not printing `{{ time }}` at all, even when devtools shows the console.logs.

What am I missing?

Comment: Most probably `$scope.$apply()` call after setting the time.

Comment: @Chandermani Thanks, that was the missing piece! Can you post it as an answer si I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `$scope.$apply()`, as the updates are happening outside of Angular context, $scope.$apply is required.

I guess this is the most common issue people stumble upon when using angular. So anytime one sees data binding not working, calling the $apply method should be the first thing to try :)